# Can't launch Ubuntu software from toolbar

Tags: 20.04, updates, launcher

I' can't launch Ubuntu software from toolbar. No matter how many times I click on it, it won't work. The other icons on the toolbar seems to work fine. I'm a newbie in the Linux world.I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Do you have networking enabled?  The first thing Ubuntu Software does is (try to) download catalogues and ratings.

Comment: It's happening to me as well in Ubuntu 21.04. Run `snap-store` in a terminal to see what error it gives you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't open snap-store](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344650/cant-open-snap-store)

Comment: Thanks guys. It started working again, out of the blue.