# Can't open snap-store

Tags: 20.04, snap-store

I am trying to open `snap-store` and it is not opening. This seems to be a problem for opening .deb packages as well.

I get this response when I try to open it on a terminal with `sudo snap-store`:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.locale” has path “/system/locale/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.proxy” has path “/system/proxy/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.proxy.http” has path “/system/proxy/http/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.proxy.https” has path “/system/proxy/https/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.proxy.ftp” has path “/system/proxy/ftp/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.proxy.socks” has path “/system/proxy/socks/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
/snap/snap-store/518/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3-0/gtk-query-immodules-3.0: symbol lookup error: /snap/snap-store/518/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined symbol: atk_plug_set_child
ERROR: /snap/snap-store/518/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3-0/gtk-query-immodules-3.0 exited abnormally with status 127
/snap/snap-store/518/usr/bin/snap-store: symbol lookup error: /snap/snap-store/518/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined symbol: atk_plug_set_child
```

I've tried removing and reinstalling `snap-store`, but that didn't help. Snap version is 2.50.1 (if that helps). If you need any information I will provide it. I don't know how to solve this and nothing I've found online has been helpful.

I also saw a post where someone said they solved what looked like a similar error by looking at the output of `ldd /usr/bin/gedit`, but I have no idea what it's about. Here's the output for that though:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe043ec000)
libgedit-3.36.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gedit/libgedit-3.36.so (0x00007f1471f26000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f1471ea4000)
libgio-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f1471cc3000)
libtepl-4.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtepl-4.so.0 (0x00007f1471c89000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1471a97000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f147196e000)
libgtk-3.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0 (0x00007f14711bb000)
libgdk-3.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0 (0x00007f14710b6000)
libpango-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f1471067000)
libatk-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f147103d000)
libcairo.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007f1470f1a000)
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f1470ef2000)
libgtksourceview-4.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtksourceview-4.so.0 (0x00007f1470e51000)
libamtk-5.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libamtk-5.so.0 (0x00007f1470e3f000)
libgirepository-1.0.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgirepository-1.0.so.1 (0x00007f1470e07000)
libpeas-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpeas-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f1470ded000)
libpeas-gtk-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpeas-gtk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f1470ddc000)
libX11.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f1470c9f000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f1470b4e000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1470b2b000)
libffi.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7 (0x00007f1470b1f000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f1470b19000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f1470afd000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1470af7000)
libmount.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1 (0x00007f1470a95000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f1470a6a000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f1470a4e000)
libxml2.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f1470894000)
libuchardet.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuchardet.so.0 (0x00007f147086f000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1472019000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f14707fc000)
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f14707e8000)
libXi.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f14707d6000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f14707ce000)
libcairo-gobject.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo-gobject.so.2 (0x00007f14707c2000)
libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f147078b000)
libepoxy.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libepoxy.so.0 (0x00007f1470658000)
libfribidi.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfribidi.so.0 (0x00007f1470639000)
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f1470620000)
libharfbuzz.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f147051b000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f14704d4000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f1470415000)
libXinerama.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007f147040e000)
libXrandr.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007f1470401000)
libXcursor.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007f14703f4000)
libXcomposite.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007f14703ef000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f14703ea000)
libxkbcommon.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007f14703a8000)
libwayland-cursor.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.so.0 (0x00007f147039d000)
libwayland-egl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1 (0x00007f1470396000)
libwayland-client.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0 (0x00007f1470385000)
libXext.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f1470370000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f1470365000)
libthai.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0x00007f147035a000)
libpixman-1.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007f14702b1000)
libpng16.so.16 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f1470279000)
libxcb-shm.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f1470274000)
libxcb.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f147024a000)
libxcb-render.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007f147023b000)
libXrender.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f1470031000)
libblkid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007f146ffd8000)
libpcre2-8.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007f146ff48000)
libicuuc.so.66 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.66 (0x00007f146fd62000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f146fd39000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f146fb58000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f146fb3b000)
libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f146faea000)
libatspi.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatspi.so.0 (0x00007f146fab3000)
libgraphite2.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f146fa86000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f146fa58000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f146fa4d000)
libdatrie.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0x00007f146fa43000)
libXau.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f146fa3d000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f146fa35000)
libicudata.so.66 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.66 (0x00007f146df74000)
libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f146dec3000)
libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f146dea9000)
liblz4.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f146de88000)
libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f146dd6a000)
libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f146dd47000)
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue but on 21.04.

Comment: I have the same problem in ubuntu 21.04

Comment: Mark yourself as affected in this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snap/+bug/1931380

Comment: Hey Tristan Canterbury! What do you mean by *"Snap version is 2.50.1"*? Are you talking about the version of `snapd`? Paste the output of `snap list` in your question. It might be helpful.

Comment: @Tristan ldd lists dynamic dependencies for a program so in this case you would have wanted to use ldd snap-store to see what dependencies it had.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is in the internals of the latest `snap-store` version *3.38.0-59-g494f078     2021-04-20 (518)* from default channel.
To fix it you can upgrade it to newer version by using command below

```
snap refresh snap-store --beta --ignore-running
```

Then you can use it as before.

---

Notes:

1. this method is universal for all current Ubuntu releases - 18.04 LTS, 20.04 LTS, 20.10 and 21.04.
2. we need to get official fix from Snap Store developers and switch then to default channel, [bug 1931380 was reported to launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snap/+bug/1931380).
3. if one is not happy with above solution, then one can use GNOME Software with snap plugin instead - `sudo add-apt-repository universe; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install gnome-software gnome-software-plugin-snap` .

**Update:** The bug has been fixed. If you switched to the beta channel, you should switch back to stable with the following command:

```
snap refresh snap-store --stable
```

Comment: it worked for me, thanks !!

Comment: Was this due to background update of some snap package?

Comment: Thank you ! it works but with warnings:

14:35:39:0215 dbind Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-6W0MTNAJfZ: No such file or directory
14:35:39:0240 Gtk Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1566:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name
...

Comment: Will this cause any issues in the future? Seems like installing from the candidate channel could cause other headaches down the line

Comment: "we need to get official fix from Snap Store developers and switch then to default channel"

Answer (score 3):

From the information in the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1931380), a beta version with fix is already available. It can be installed with:

```
snap refresh snap-store --beta --ignore-running
```

Tried it, works.