# Ubuntu 21.04 - Ubuntu Software not opening

Tags: snap, 21.04, ubuntu-store, snap-store

Yesterday Ubuntu Software was working but today it isn't. Running `snap-store` shows the following error

```
/snap/snap-store/518/usr/bin/snap-store: symbol lookup error: /snap/snap-store/518/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined symbol: atk_plug_set_child
```

These two updates happened since the last time it worked (yesterday that I installed Spotify)

```
Start-Date: 2021-06-08  09:27:43
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libgnome-autoar-0-0:amd64 (0.3.1-1, 0.3.1-1ubuntu0.1)
End-Date: 2021-06-08  09:27:43

Start-Date: 2021-06-08  15:06:56
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.223'
Upgrade: python3-distupgrade:amd64 (1:21.04.11, 1:21.04.12), libgoa-1.0-common:amd64 (3.38.1-1ubuntu1, 3.38.1-1ubuntu1.1), ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:amd64 (1:21.04.11, 1:21.04.12), libgoa-1.0-0b:amd64 (3.38.1-1ubuntu1, 3.38.1-1ubuntu1.1), libgoa-backend-1.0-1:amd64 (3.38.1-1ubuntu1, 3.38.1-1ubuntu1.1), gnome-online-accounts:amd64 (3.38.1-1ubuntu1, 3.38.1-1ubuntu1.1), gir1.2-goa-1.0:amd64 (3.38.1-1ubuntu1, 3.38.1-1ubuntu1.1), ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:amd64 (1:21.04.11, 1:21.04.12)
End-Date: 2021-06-08  15:06:57
```

Additionally `snap-changes` gives me one entry for today

```
7    Done    today at 15:36 -05  today at 15:36 -05  Auto-refresh snap "gnome-3-34-1804"
```

and `snap tasks 7` shows

```
Status  Spawn               Ready               Summary
Done    today at 15:36 -05  today at 15:36 -05  Ensure prerequisites for "gnome-3-34-1804" are available
Done    today at 15:36 -05  today at 15:36 -05  Download snap "gnome-3-34-1804" (72) from channel "latest/stable/ubuntu-21.04"
Done    today at 15:36 -05  today at 15:36 -05  Fetch and check assertions for snap "gnome-3-34-1804" (72)
Done    today at 15:36 -05  today at 15:36 -05  Mount snap "gnome-3-34-1804" (72)
Done    today at 15:36 -05  today at 15:36 -05  Run pre-refresh hook of "gnome-3-34-1804" snap if present
Done    today at 15:36 -05  today at 15:36 -05  Stop snap "gnome-3-34-1804" services
Done    today at 15:36 -05  today at 15:36 -05  Remove aliases for snap "gnome-3-34-1804"
Done    today at 15:36 -05  today at 15:36 -05  Make current revision for snap "gnome-3-34-1804" unavailable
Done    today at 15:36 -05  today at 15:36 -05  Copy snap "gnome-3-34-1804" data
Done    today at 15:36 -05  today at 15:36 -05  Setup snap "gnome-3-34-1804" (72) security profiles
Done    today at 15:36 -05  today at 15:36 -05  Make snap "gnome-3-34-1804" (72) available to the system
Done    today at 15:36 -05  today at 15:36 -05  Automatically connect eligible plugs and slots of snap "gnome-3-34-1804"
Done    today at 15:36 -05  today at 15:36 -05  Set automatic aliases for snap "gnome-3-34-1804"
Done    today at 15:36 -05  today at 15:36 -05  Setup snap "gnome-3-34-1804" aliases
Done    today at 15:36 -05  today at 15:36 -05  Run post-refresh hook of "gnome-3-34-1804" snap if present
Done    today at 15:36 -05  today at 15:36 -05  Start snap "gnome-3-34-1804" (72) services
Done    today at 15:36 -05  today at 15:36 -05  Clean up "gnome-3-34-1804" (72) install
Done    today at 15:36 -05  today at 15:36 -05  Run configure hook of "gnome-3-34-1804" snap if present
Done    today at 15:36 -05  today at 15:36 -05  Run health check of "gnome-3-34-1804" snap
Done    today at 15:36 -05  today at 15:36 -05  Consider re-refresh of "gnome-3-34-1804"

......................................................................
Consider re-refresh of "gnome-3-34-1804"

2021-06-08T15:36:57-05:00 INFO No re-refreshes found.
```

I've tried re-installing the snap-store and gnome-3-34-1804 but it didn't work.

Comment: See this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1344697/66509 .

Comment: @David Opened a ticket here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snap/+bug/1931380

Comment: Great! It works, thanks for the help and for opening the ticket

Answer (score 2):

Try to install the candidate version. It worked for me.

```bsh
snap remove snap-store
snap install snap-store --candidate
```

**Note:** After [bug 1931380](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snap/+bug/1931380) gets fixed, you will need to switch back to the default channel.

**Update:** the default channel has fixed the bug. You should automatically get the stable refresh within 24 hours. If you switched to the candidate channel, you will need to switch back to default.

```bsh
$ snap refresh
```

[image]