# Software Catalogue/Center Doesn't Open

Tags: software-center

When I double click on the item "software catalogue/center" (the orange avatar) it seems he is searching, but nothing comes up. I just installed Ubuntu with the complete package but that didnt change it.

What to do?

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install gnome-software` followed by `sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-snap`

Comment: See this answer  - https://askubuntu.com/a/1344697/66509 .

Comment: To get it to run I usually have to do the following in a terminal: `killall snap-store` or if you are running the gnome-software version of the Ubuntu store then `killall gnome-software` then try running again from the icon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't open snap-store](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344650/cant-open-snap-store)