# Gnome/Ubuntu Software not Launching

Tags: software-center, gnome-software

Gnome/Ubuntu Software is not launching by clicking on the icon on the dock, or the one on the application list. There are no errors. Even so,

```
gnome-software
```

launches Gnome/Ubuntu Software well. Could please tell me what might be wrong?

Comment: when it launches, which icon is shown in the dock? the orange one or the blue and white one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't open snap-store](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344650/cant-open-snap-store)

Comment: Not the orange one. Blue and white one, yes @24601

Comment: I ran the following commands:  `snap remove snap-store` and `snap install snap-store --candidate`; the orange one disappeared, and the blue&white one called software is working on the applications list @N0rbert

Comment: Thank you very much all!