# Ubuntu Software application has dissappeared

Tags: ubuntu-store, snap-store

I followed the suggestion ([Can't open snap-store](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344650/cant-open-snap-store)) to fix the recent breakage of the snap store, but now my "Ubuntu Software" desktop app has completely disappeared.  Is there any way to get it back?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't open snap-store](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344650/cant-open-snap-store)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was easier to fix than anticipated, this restored it easily enough:

```
snap remove snap-store
snap install snap-store
```

Albeit, still broken due to the issue linked in the OP.  But I think I'll just be patient and wait for that issue to be fixed.

Comment: Use `snap remove snap-store; snap install snap-store --candidate` instead. Or use `sudo apt-get install gnome-software gnome-software-plugin-snap` .

Comment: Ah thanks, if you could also post that on the original question that I linked it would probably help a lot of people.