# Ubuntu launching Software instead of Snap Store

Tags: snap-store

I click on SNAP STORE and it's SOFTWARE that opens instead (Ubuntu Software 3.38.1)
So I checked the command associated to the icon in the launch menu and everything seems fine

`env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/snap-store_snap-store.desktop /snap/bin/snap-store %U`

Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344650/cant-open-snap-store?rq=1) help you?

Answer (score 0):

"Ubuntu software" and "Snap store" are the same. It is a custom version of the Gnome Software center, packed as a snap. By default, you only have "Ubuntu software", a.k.a. "Snap store" on your computer. The regular Gnome Software optionally is available for install as well.

Comment: On my system I have both. Snap Store and Ubuntu Software. If I remember well, I have installed Snap Store shortly after installing Ubuntu. Shouldn't clicking on Snap STore opens that specific software instead of redirecting to Ubuntu Software???